# How to stop and tear down embedded Cassandra in JUnit Tests

Tags: java, junit, cassandra, embedded-cassandra

i am using Cassandra in several JUnit Tests Classes. 
The Problem:
I do not know how to tear down/drop the cassandra correct after finishing a Test.
I do not want to reuse the same instance of the Cassandra in other Tests or Testclasses, this is thre reason why i want to stop and tear down the DB after each Test.

The Question:
How can i tear down the Embedded Cassandra ?

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
  EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper.startEmbeddedCassandra(EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper.DEFAULT_CASSANDRA_YML_FILE,
                                                     CASSANDRA_SETUP_TIMEOUT_IN_MILLIS);

  cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint(CASSANDRA_HOST).withPort(CASSANDRA_PORT).build();
  final Session session = cluster.connect();

  String cql = "create keyspace IF NOT EXISTS " + CASSANDRA_KEYSPACE
             + " with replication={'class':'NetworkTopologyStrategy','datacenter1':1};";
  System.out.println(cql);
  session.execute(cql);

  cql = "USE " + CASSANDRA_KEYSPACE + ";";
  System.out.println(cql);
  session.execute(cql);
}

 @After
 public void tearDown() throws Exception {
   EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper.cleanEmbeddedCassandra();
   session.close();
   cluster.close();

  //Stop is not working, due to deprectated:
  //EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper.stopEmbeddedCassandra();
 }
```